# Draw two sns.jointplot in one figure

Tags: python, seaborn

I want to draw to plot of kind sns.jointplot in one figure like this picture
[image]

I have this code

```
sns.jointplot (draw_D(lst_1)[0], draw_D(lst_1)[1], color = 'r') 
sns.jointplot (draw_D(lst_2)[0], draw_D(lst_2)[1], color = 'b')
```

and i get them separated

Answer (score 0):

I think this `jointplot` is using for **3 dimensional** data.

> (Just a dataset, in your case have two dataset: `lst_1` & `lst_2`)

Example:

```py
penguins = sns.load_dataset("penguins")

sns.jointplot(data=penguins, x="bill_length_mm", y="bill_depth_mm", hue="species")
```

As you can see:

> 1. Only one dataset: `penguins`
> 2. Three dimensional for this dataset: `bill_length_mm`, `bill_depth_mm`, `species`

If you want to draw two dataset in one figure, you should check:

> - Are this two dataset have same variables?
> - Looks up your picture, the dataset have 3 variables: `bill_length_mm`, `bill_depth_mm`, `species`
> - Have your dataset like this?